# Get second layer class type using string

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I have a type for 'fields' with many properties inside. I get the property needed reflectively using :

```
public object this[string propertyName]
{
    get
    {
        Type myType = typeof(Fields);
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        return myPropInfo.GetValue(this, null);
    }
    set
    {
        Type myType = typeof(Fields);
        PropertyInfo myPropInfo = myType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        myPropInfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }

}
```

Which functions well when a simple type is needed, such as string:

```
  public void UpdateData(string location, string data){
     Fields dataUpdate = new Fields();
     dataUpdate[location] = data;
     ComHandler.SendDataUpdate(dataUpdate);
}
```

I need to know how to get the type of this 'dataUpdate[location]' for instances that are not string. I have tried using

```
typeof(dataUpdate[location]) 
if(dataUpdate[location] is CustomField)
   //do work
else
   //is a string
```

but can't find any resource to get this to work.

Edit for answer

I ended up using a try catch statement to determine what type the item is based on if it could be converted to CustomField or if it was just a string.

Comment: wow, can you please add few words about purpose of such approach? why `dataUpdate["location"]` instead of `dataUpdate.Location`?

Comment: `if (dataUpdate[location]?.GetType() == typeof(CustomField))`? won't work though if the returned value is null.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy dataUpdate.Location doesn't exist, this is a string to identify witch property of Fields needs to be set to the data value

Comment: @vipersassassin it should exist. Otherwise `myType.GetProperty(propertyName)` will return `null`

Comment: @RenéVogt I just tried your suggestion and it appears that that doesn't work either.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy location is a string, such as "customfield_10258" that is being searched for, I have no property dataUpdate.location.

Comment: @vipersassassin ok, got you. But why you have class with properties which you are not able to use? Probably you should have single property called `Locations` which will hold something like `Dictionary<string,locationType>`. And you will be able to get location by name `dataUpdate.Locations[location]`

Comment: Are you looking for this? [PropertyInfo.PropertyType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.propertytype(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You're making things complicated. First indication of difficult to maintain is `dataUpdate[location] is CustomField`? What exactly are you trying to do with whole approach? Probably we could start on that?

Comment: dataUpdate contains about 70 properties that could be requested to be updated, I just don't know which is being updated. To access this I get `dataUpdate[location]` which is now accessible as a type, either string or CustomField. I updated the question to include that since there are only two items, a try catch will work for now. If this goes to different types (int, float, string, CustomField, List<T>) I would have to find a better method to determine which is actually occurring.